# Sandboxing Social Sharing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, social-networking, sandbox

I'd like to use social sharing widgets (e.g. Facebook Like, Twitter Tweet, etc) on my site, but I don't want to directly embed third-party script tags.  I'd like my site to only run either trusted or sandboxed code.

- [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) might work, but it requires the third-party code be written specifically to accommodate Caja.
- Content Security Policy might work, but it is [sparsely implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy), especially with IE (even 10) and there's no good way to detect if it's even present.

Is there a solution to this?  Or do I have to choose between not having the buttons at all and running untrusted JavaScript?

Additional context: I'd like to run my entire site on HTTPS, but I also want to have sharing buttons.  I don't want to potentially leak secure cookies to Facebook or Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't trust third-party JavaScript (and I don't blame you, it's scary!), your best bet is to use the `iframe` implementations that these social networks provide. For instance, you can include a Facebook "Like" button by adding the following frame to your site:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[PAGE_URL_GOES_HERE]&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#using-an-iframe has details on a similar setup for Twitter.

Encapsulating the code in an `iframe` gives you some measure of protection against the content of the frame, as it can't reach up into the parent to grab data or manipulate your code.

You can increase the level of protection by sandboxing the `iframe` via the (cleverly named) `sandbox` attribute. For instance:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-script allow-same-origin" src="..."></iframe>
```

would load a page into an `iframe`, and allow it to run script with access to its origin (but still not the parent's origin). It would not, however, be able to navigate the top level document, load plugins, etc. Sandboxing is supported in Chrome, Safari, Firefox 18+, and IE9 (I think. Might be 10.).

Comment: Thanks!  Facebook doesn't advertise the IFRAME implementation terribly well in that they don't provide a generator for it, so I appreciate the code snippet above.  After doing more research, only IE10 supports the sandbox attribute, though IE6-IE9 support security=restricted, which might be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to potentially leak secure cookies to Facebook or Twitter.

If you are afraid that when browser will go and fetch twitter/facebok JS  it will pass on your website cookies, then it won't. But if you included some js it can access cookies by document.cookies. Moreover I don't think that rewriting is really an option, too much work, and what if it changes?

Security vs. usability was always a battle. I would recoomend not including those buttons on sites with sensitive informations on it. And just pray for nothing bad to happen :) Plus you may add adiitional protection mechanisms like requesting to reauthenticate before any change to user data or any sensitive data.